# How to insert sample data in a table in loopback 4?

Tags: loopback4

```
import { DefaultStatus } from './models/default-status.model';
import { MyApplication } from './application';
import {
  UserRepository,
  UserCredentialsRepository
} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
import { DefaultStatusRepository } from './repositories/default-status.repository';

export async function migrate(args: string[]) {
  const existingSchema = args.includes('--rebuild') ? 'drop' : 'alter';

  const app = new MyApplication();
  await app.boot();
  app.repository(UserRepository);
  app.repository(UserCredentialsRepository);
  await app.migrateSchema({ existingSchema });
  app.dataSource;

  // Inserting data here
  (await app.getRepository(DefaultStatusRepository)).create({
    key: "Identified",
    value: 1
  } as DefaultStatus);

  process.exit(0);
}

migrate(process.argv).catch(err => {
  console.error('Cannot migrate database schema', err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

I am trying to insert the data in table 'default-status' but it doesn't work. I also don't get any errors. I tried hooking this to migration script. Is there any other way to insert the data in a table without writing the code in the controller?

Comment: try this `await (await app.getRepository(DefaultStatusRepository)).create({
    key: "Identified",
    value: 1
  } as DefaultStatus);`

Comment: Try calling `await app.start()` before calling `.create()`, but after `await app.boot()`